# Do all SVG paths have to start with a Move?

Tags: svg

I tried the following SVG path in my Firefox

```
<svg>
    <path d="M50,50 l100,0 l0,100 l-100,0 Z"/>
</svg>
```

And it makes a pretty square as expected. However this path doesn't draw anything:

```
<svg>
    <path d="L50,50 l100,0 l0,100 l-100,0 Z"/>
</svg>
```

I would expect the previous command to have the same behaviour as:

```
<svg>
    <path d="M0,0 L50,50 l100,0 l0,100 l-100,0 Z"/>
</svg>
```

Which works. Is that correct behaviour?

If I write an SVG parser, can I expect a move command at the start of every path?

Comment: And just as important: If I write code that generates SVG paths, is it important to always start my path with a Move command?

Comment: If you intend writing an SVG parser or generator, you really ought to read the SVG specification.  Which will answer all questions like this.

Comment: Specifically [this bit of it](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html#PathDataBNF)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per [the SVG specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html#PathDataMovetoCommands)

> A path data segment (if there is one) must begin with a "moveto" command.